# Does date_default_timezone_set Change The Global Timezone

Tags: php, laravel

I inherited a Laravel project where the original dev handled multiple users time zone calculations by doing

```
date_default_timezone_set($business->timezone);
$time = (int)date("H");
if($time < $business->open_time){
    //business is not open yet.
}
```

(This logic is used all over the place as well. There are 68 instances of date_default_timezone_set being called)

My concern is that if the timezone is set, and then another user runs code that grabs the date that it will be the wrong timezone. Is this a valid concern or can I just leave the code as is for now until replacing all of this with the Carbon library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel's global time zone is set by the `timezone` parameter of `config/app.php`(laravel 5.X). If you use date_default_timezone_set, it will only take effect in the current code scope and will not affect other places.

```
public function custom(Request $request){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Pyongyang');
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2021-07-27 11:35:48
}

public function local(Request $request){
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2021-07-27 10:35:48,my gloabl timezone is Asia/Shanghai
}
```

Comment: That's great to hear. Still gonna switch to carbon eventually, but at least the app wont catch on fire, per say. lol

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to handling multiple user timezones its best to use timestamps instead of Date Time functions. Timestamps are universal to store. And for output can be translated into any timezone.